# url restructure or rewrite having $_GET variables

Tags: url-rewriting

I am currently trying to rewrite or restructure a url.. I have three search fields, after fullfiling it when user click search it takes you to oter page and link forms like

"http://goasquare.com/jobs/?keywords=res&categories%5B%5D=44&location=goa&search_region=&submit=&filter_job_type%5B%5D="

i just want to restructure it like below url 
http://goasquare.com/jobs/%keyword%/%category%/%location%

i have tried many solutions but not workin , please help me

Comment: i have tried code below

'add_action( 'init', 'wpse16819_init' );
function wpse16819_init()
{
    
   
   
 add_rewrite_rule( '/jobs/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=jobs&keywords=$matches[90]&categories=$matches[91]&location=$matches[92]', 'top' );
   
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse16819_query_vars' );
function wpse16819_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'keywords';
 $query_vars[] = 'categories';
 $query_vars[] = 'location';
 

    return $query_vars;
}'

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are after pretty URLs for your form GET sending form. There are two steps involved here.

*First* you need to prevent the default behaviour of submit form buttons: grabbing the `<form>` action attribute (e.g. `<form action="http://foo.com">`) and adding to it the values of the inputs as URL parameters (GET parameters). You need to use JavaScript for this - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658595/get-form-values-to-create-a-custom-url) and its answers.

Now that you have the friendly URL and redirecting to it, you need to "help" WordPress make sense of it.
So, *secondly*, you need to add a new rewrite rule that will map the URL to variables as needed by your server-side logic. This code should get you started (I assumed the slug of your page is `jobs`):

```
add_rewrite_rule( '/jobs/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=jobs&keywords=$matches[1]&categories=$matches[2]&location=$matches[3]', 'top' );
```

Here is starter JavaScript for you to get going (it is based on jQuery, not vanilla JS):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function(){
        var $form = $("#someform");
        $form.on('submit', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          // Create the new URL
          var new_url = $form.attr('action') + "/" + encodeURIComponent($form.find("input[name=keywords]").first().val()) + "/" + encodeURIComponent($form.find("input[name=categories]").first().val()) + "/" + encodeURIComponent($form.find("input[name=location]").first().val()) + "/";
          // This alert is just to help you see the URL - delete it when no needed
          alert(new_url);

          // Now we will redirect to the URL
          window.location.replace(new_url);

          // We need to return false to stop the normal form submission
          return false;
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

If you find it easier, here is [the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vladolaru/18vgyr9x/26/) for the code above.

Comment: sorry but i am not really good at javascript,, so if u can please help me in this, and i think wil be using add_rewrite_rule on init hook?

Comment: Yes, the `init` hook should be fine for adding rewrite rules. Also, don't forget to flush the rewrite rules after you make changes to the code (WP Admin -> Settings -> Permalinks and click Save).

Comment: I've updated my answer with the JS starter code.

Comment: really thankful for doing this but problem is not resolved yet,,it just not working,,, when the form submit it just make url more messy

http://goasquare.com/jobs/resturant/zoo/goa?keywords=resturant&categories%5B%5D=79&location=goa&search_region=&submit=&filter_job_type%5B%5D=

please help me out of this hell problem

Comment: I have updated my JS because I haven't added the onLoad logic. Simply put the script above inline, near your form, and you should be good to go.

Comment: again really grateful for helping me out,, i have done exactly the same you told but now i am having blank screen and many time it gives error page not found

Comment: It is really hard to help you further without seeing your exact full situation. Sorry about it.

Comment: i can provide you my project login credentials if you can please please take a deep look into it,, i will be really gratefull to you